# HTML5/Javascript-app on Android freezing while scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, ios, eclipse, html

I'm currently learning multi-platform web-app development through HTML5
and starting with Android (Eclipse kepler 1), using the webviews. It's very simple so far, I'm trying 
to get the "myimage1" element to gradually move to 500 px below it's original position using setInterval().

On the PC browsers all is working fine, but on the .apk the "myimage1"-element will not move visually when I'm scrolling over the screen - it freezes instead.
The app does not pause but operates invisible so when I let go, the "myimage1" continues from where it should be at that time.

My question is not so much about the setInterval() method on its own: What forces are causing the web-app to freeze during scrolling in Android and can it be fixed without using native android-code? (I've read this also happens on iOS, so additional suggestions concerning iOS are welcome),

The js code:

```
<script>  
  var Tick=setInterval(function(){onTick()},20);
  var dist=0;

  function onTick()
  {
  dist+=1;
  document.getElementById("myimage1").style.position="fixed";
  document.getElementById("myimage1").style.top=dist + "px";
  if (dist>500) stopTick();
  }

  function stopTick()
  {
  window.clearInterval(Tick)
  }

  </script>
```

Thanks in advance